# How to compile a library without Ivy?

Tags: javascript, node.js, angular, typescript, npm

I'm publishing a library and when I cd to `dist/my-library` I get the message:

> ERROR: Trying to publish a package that has been compiled by Ivy. This is not allowed.
>   Please delete and rebuild the package, without compiling with Ivy, before attempting to publish.

How do we rebuild without Ivy?

Comment: Have you tried to disable ivy? `"enableIvy": false`?

Comment: Do we put that in angular.json

Comment: It should be in tsconfig.json file as part of `angularCompilerOptions`

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Within the library project there is a `tsconfig.lib.json` file.  Here's my Angular compiler configuration:

```
  "angularCompilerOptions": {
    "skipTemplateCodegen": true,
    "strictMetadataEmit": true,
    "enableResourceInlining": true,
    "enableIvy": false
  },
```

Comment: If I have ng13 and I want to compile everything with Ivy?

Answer (score 12):

**Fix for `angular 9.x.x`**

If you migrated your app to angular 9 and you see this kind of error, make sure to build your library with `--prod` option it will not build with IVY

```
ng build yourLibraryName --prod
```

When you will pass `--prod` it will build without the ivy option and it will be allowed to be published.

As part of the migration, angular CLI create `tsconfig.lib.prod.json` and configure to not use IVY and you are all set

Answer (score 5):

To Fix this warning:

Try to disable Ivy in `tsconfig.lib.json` by adding below line to `"angularCompilerOptions"` :-

`"enableIvy": false`

**Or**

build with `--prod`

example: `ng build your-package-name --prod`