# angular 9 library publish error "Trying to publish a package that has been compiled by Ivy"

Tags: angular, angular-cli, angular-library, angular-cli-v9

I migrated my `angular 8.x.x` project to `angular 9.x.x` and when I try to publish my library, it fails with below error

> npm ERR! @candiman/website@9.0.0 prepublishOnly: `node --eval "console.error('ERROR: Trying to publish a package that has been compiled by Ivy. This is not allowed.\nPlease delete and rebuild the package, without compiling with Ivy, before attempting to publish.\n')" && exit 1`

is there anything changed in the `angular 9`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to compile a library without Ivy?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59113052/how-to-compile-a-library-without-ivy)

Comment: this issue is related to angular 9 migration @R.Richards. the other one is related to normal and most of the people will fall into this issue as it will pop up during migration.

Answer (score 74, accepted):

**UPDATE ANGULAR 12**

using the `--configuration production` option while building the library fixed my issue

```
ng build --configuration production
```

---

Original answer:

using `--prod` option while building the library fixed my issue

```
ng build yourLibraryName --prod
```

Comment: And what is your --prod configuration?

Comment: actually --prod is a flag passed to angular cli configuration to say its a prod build so dont do a aot/ivy build

Comment: Yes - but it still has to be set up as `production` configuration for your library in `angular.json` file - otherwise you will get an error saying there is no production configuration when you try to run in.

Comment: @codeepic, hann, good point. I actuality  did not tried that. thanks for adding that as a note

Comment: adding --prod worked
and no, you should not write production. The environment config and the flag --prod are 2 different things

Comment: @AniruddhaDas also be sure to do `ng build yourLibraryName --prod` **after** `ng test --watch=false`. Ng test will also compile your library getting then the error: `ERROR: Trying to publish a package that has been compiled by NGCC. This is not allowed.`

Comment: Wouldn't it be great if this was included in the output message!??!!!!

Answer (score 24):

## Fix for Angular 12+ missing component style issue

On Angular 12, while using:

```
ng build --configuration production
```

indeed solved the original issue for me, it also introduced a new one: the styles of my library component where completely missing.

I've solved this other problem by replacing:

```
  "angularCompilerOptions": {
    "enableIvy": false
  }
```

with:

```
  "angularCompilerOptions": {
    "compilationMode": "partial"
  }
```

in `projects/my-library/tsconfig.lib.prod.json`

Source: https://angular.io/guide/creating-libraries#building-libraries-with-ivy

Answer (score 23):

According to official Angular docs https://angular.io/guide/ivy#opting-out-of-ivy-in-version-9

it is better to opt out from Ivy compiler to use the older View Engine when building and publishing your library by adding this line:

`enableIvy: false`

to angularCompilerOptions in tsconfig.json file at the root of your library as can be seen below;

[image]

I've tried it after updating my Angular library to Angular version 9 and this one small change worked like a charm.

Answer (score 8):

In my case none of the solutions above worked. I noticed however that in the `package.json` of my library in the dist folder there is an newly added script (probably added because of [this](https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/d1ea1f4c7f3358b730b0d94e65b00bc28cae279c/packages/compiler-cli/ngcc/src/packages/build_marker.ts#L93)):

```
  "scripts": {
    "prepublishOnly": "node --eval \"console.error('ERROR: Trying to publish a package that has been compiled by NGCC. This is not allowed.\\nPlease delete and rebuild the package, without compiling with NGCC, before attempting to publish.\\nNote that NGCC may have been run by importing this package into another project that is being built with Ivy enabled.\\n')\" && exit 1"
  }
```

SO here either remove/replace the `prepublishOnly` script or publish using `npm publish --ignore-scripts`

Comment: Is it because you're trying to publish a package that starts from 'ng-'?

Answer (score 6):

While building my libraries with `ng build --prod` and `enableIvy = false` in `tsconfig.lib.json` I was getting the same "prepublishOnly" script added to my workspace `package.json` as [Melchia](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64381007/15289340) had.

The reason why seems to be related to using a private repository via `publishConfig/registry` in each library's `package.json`, as stated in https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/37973#issuecomment-656136865

When building Angular libraries for publishing, use `ng build --prod`, `enableIvy = false` in library's `tsconfig.json` and, if working with a private repository, `npm publish --ignore-scripts`

Answer (score 3):

In addition to adding the `--prod` flag, if you're running on a really old version, you'll also need the following update to `angular.json`:

```
    "myproject": {
      ...
      "architect": {
        "build": {
          ...
          "configurations": {
            "production": {
              "tsConfig": "projects/mypath/tsconfig.lib.prod.json"
            }
          }
        },
```

with the content of that file being:

```
{
  "extends": "./tsconfig.lib.json",
  "angularCompilerOptions": {
    "enableIvy": false
  }
}
```

You can check if you're on such an old version if you still have the following lines in `angular.json`:

```
            "production": {
              "project": "projects/tsmean/spinner/ng-package.prod.json"
            }
```

Answer (score 3):

Solved this by simply adding the following to `tsconfig.lib.prod.json`

```
"angularCompilerOptions": {
    "compilationMode": "partial",
}
```

Comment: Thanks!!, really not good not finding this in angular Doc, at least not so easy

Comment: I had to run production command with flag `--configuration production` that forced to pick `.prod.json` configs

Answer (score 2):

In your `angular.json` file, you have a `build` object in your library tree. Inside `build`, you have a `configurations` object, that contains a `production` object and probably a `development` object too.

Inside `build` object define a new property called `defaultConfiguration`, and set the value: `production` that match with the name of the `production` property inside `configurations` object.

Your `angular.json` file should look like this:

```
"architect": {
  build": {
    "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-ng-packagr:build",
    "options": {
      "tsConfig": "projects/ngx-custom-tooltip/tsconfig.lib.json",
      "project": "projects/ngx-custom-tooltip/ng-package.json"
    },
    "configurations": {
      "production": {
        "tsConfig": "projects/ngx-custom-tooltip/tsconfig.lib.prod.json"
      },
      "development": {
        "tsConfig": "projects/ngx-custom-tooltip/tsconfig.lib.json"
      }
    },
    "defaultConfiguration": "production"
  },
  ...
}
```

Your `tsconfig.lib.prod.json` should contains this object:

```
"angularCompilerOptions": {
  "enableIvy": false
}
```

Finally, yo can execute `ng build your-library-name`

Answer (score 1):

Adding

"compilationMode": "partial"

**to**

"angularCompilerOptions": {

}

Solved my problem

Comment: This has already been mentioned in [Francesco's anser](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68197875/2227743).

Comment: Actually this is the exact solution, no long modification needed as discussed in answer you are referencing

Answer (score 0):

As per the latest (Version 12+) guidelines by Angular is that don't use **full compilation** mode for publishing your library to npm.

The Solution is to set your configuration Accordingly in `tsconfig.lib.json` or `tsconfig.lib.prod.json`

If using an Angular version less than 12 you can go with ivy false.

```
"angularCompilerOptions": {
   "enableIvy": false
 }
```

From Angular version 12 Ivy will consider true by default. We can't control it directly as Angular will complain.

So the correct suggested option to publish your library is:

```
"angularCompilerOptions": {
"compilationMode": "partial",
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Angular team doesn't allow to publish library in full Ivy mode to NPM as it is highly probable that applications that will consume it, will be built using partial Ivy mode. This will cause compatibility problems.

So, to get out of this situation, you may use the following hack:

**Assumption:** You will ensure that your consumer application & library are built using full Ivy mode. And any application built using partial Ivy mode will not consume your library. Moreover, both application and library are built using exact same version of Angular.

**Hack:** Just before publishing your library, you can remove the script from `dist/.../package.json`, that prevents the library from publishing.

**More information:** This has been discussed at length with Angular team [here](https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/41048). To summarize you may start reading the thread from [here](https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/41048#issuecomment-791441353).